# Unable to add data in archive table in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I wrote the code to update my table (SecurityQuestionAnswer) with new security password questions and move to old questions to another table (SecurityQuestionAnswersArchives). Total no of security questions is 3. I am able to update the current table, but when I add the same rows to history table, it shows weird data: only two records are added instead of 3 and the data is also duplicated. My code is as follows:

```
if (oldQuestions.Any())
        {
            var oldquestionstoarchivelist = new List<SecurityQuestionAnswersArchives>();
            var  oldquestionstoarchive =new SecurityQuestionAnswersArchives();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                oldquestionstoarchive.Id = oldQuestions[i].Id;
                oldquestionstoarchive.SecurityQuestionId = oldQuestions[i].SecurityQuestionId;
                oldquestionstoarchive.Answer = oldQuestions[i].Answer;
                oldquestionstoarchive.UpdateDate = oldQuestions[i].UpdateDate;
                oldquestionstoarchive.IpAddress = oldQuestions[i].IpAddress;
                oldquestionstoarchive.SecurityQuestion = oldQuestions[i].SecurityQuestion;
                oldquestionstoarchive.User = oldQuestions[i].User;
                oldquestionstoarchivelist.Add(oldquestionstoarchive);
            }
            user.SecurityQuestionAnswersArchives = oldquestionstoarchivelist;
            //await Store.UpdateAsync(user);
            _dbContext.ArchiveSecurityQuestionAnswers.AddRange(oldquestionstoarchivelist);
            _dbContext.SecurityQuestionAnswers.RemoveRange(oldQuestions);
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            oldquestionstoarchivelist.Clear();

        }
```

**UPDATE 1**

The loop looks fine, It iterates three times(0,1,2), which is expected. First issue is with `AddRange` function to which I was passing a list , but it takes an `IEnumerable` input, I rectified it using following code.

```
IEnumerable<SecurityQuestionAnswersArchives> finalArchiveses = oldquestionstoarchivelist;
_dbContext.ArchiveSecurityQuestionAnswers.AddRange(finalArchiveses);
```

The other issue is duplicate data , which I am unable to figure out where the issue is. Please help me in finding this out.

Your help is much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Got it ! Just sharing in case anybody has same issue.
The problem was with initialization at wrong place. I moved 
var  oldquestionstoarchive =new SecurityQuestionAnswersArchives();
 in side the Forloop, now the variable will hold the unique values over each iteration.

```
var oldquestionstoarchivelist = new List<SecurityQuestionAnswersArchives>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                var oldquestionstoarchive = new SecurityQuestionAnswersArchives();
                oldquestionstoarchive.SecurityQuestionId = oldQuestions[i].SecurityQuestionId;
                oldquestionstoarchive.Answer = oldQuestions[i].Answer;
                oldquestionstoarchive.UpdateDate = oldQuestions[i].UpdateDate;
                oldquestionstoarchive.IpAddress = oldQuestions[i].IpAddress;
                oldquestionstoarchive.SecurityQuestion = oldQuestions[i].SecurityQuestion;
                oldquestionstoarchive.User = oldQuestions[i].User;
                oldquestionstoarchivelist.Add(oldquestionstoarchive);
            }
```